# asp.net core not returning public class fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I'm migrating older ASP.NET WebControllers (C#) to ASP.NET Core WebControllers.
I have lot of DTO classes with public fields (not the public properties!).
E.q.

```
class Data {
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}
```

ASP.NET Core WebController methods don't include any public fields into return, so client receives empty json objects.
Is there any way (option) to include public fields?
I do not want to modify dozens of DTO classes with lot of fields.
Thank you for any info.

I was unable to find any documentation that even mentions limitation on fields.
Note: returning of fields worked perfectly fine in ASP.NET.

Comment: Don’t use fields. Use properties. System.Text.Json only works on properties

Comment: _"I do not want to modify dozens of DTO classes with lot of fields"_ - **you will have to**: you did it incorrectly in the first-place by using fields instead of properties and never corrected it, now you have to deal with the consequences of _technical debt_.  (The guidance in official documentation has always been to prefer properties over fields, even when both are supported, this has always been the case, going back to WCF's _Data Contracts_ in 2005 and .NET Framework 1.1's serializers in 2002).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-5.0

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Huh - **TIL** that they added support for fields in .NET 5, thanks - now if only they'd add support for custom `enum`/`string` values...

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5, System.Text.Json does support serialising fields if you set `JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true`.

asp.net defines the `JsonOptions` configuration class, to provide `JsonSerializerOptions` for formatting argument and return values to / from json.

```cs
Services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});

// or

Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.NET Core WebController methods don't include any public fields
> into return, so client receives empty json objects

Well, by [default Fields are ignored during serialization and deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-7.0) consequently, you are getting null values in your clinet.

Therefore, you ought to set [`IncludeFields = true;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-7.0#properties) thus, it would consider it while serialization and deserialization.

> Is there any way (option) to include public fields?

Yes, you can achieve that, in your `program.cs` file you can configure it as following:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
 
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
    
   
});
```

**Note:** Once you set IncludeFields = true, it would no longer return empty result. If you need more information please [have a look on our official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-7.0#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-includefields).

Comment: `System.Text.Json` supports serializing `internal` types' `public` fields just fine - it uses reflection, after all, so the normal rules about type and member accessibility don't apply. See it working fine here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6jglxn

Comment: Thanks for your explanation sir, I have updated my answer. Though, I knew that but didn't think of that at this scenario. Thanks once again.